# How to store selected radiobutton value in android?

Tags: php, android

I have created 2 radio buttons for Gender(Male&Female).I want to store selected radio button value in MySQL. I am connecting Android to MySQL using PHP. In MySQL, I have taken datatype for Gender is tinyint.In PHP script I have written insert query.I want that if male is selected then 0 should be store and female is selected then 1 should be store in MySQL. For that what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Example:

let this action be done on your button click

so write this code inside your click listener

```
if(radioButton1.isSeleceted())
    String temp = radioButton1.getText().toString();
if(radioButton2.isSeleceted())
    String temp = radioButton2.getText().toString();
```

then put the temp value in your `Database`

Comment: But I want to store value of radiobutton not text.For example, 0 for male and 1 for female.So where I have to set value of radio button?

Comment: there is no male female concept in radio buttons :

u can do this... 

radioButton1.setTag("0");
radioButton2.setTag("1");


and use getTag() in above code instead of getText()

Comment: @DigmaChauhan DID u find your solution you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use database.
  you can save values in `Shared preference` .

**Ex:**

```
 if(radioButton1.isSeleceted()) {
     PrefarenceName.putString("gender","1");

 } else if(radioButton2.isSeleceted())
     PrefarenceName.putString("gender","0");
 } 

  String gendertype = prefarenceName.getString("gender");

  if(gendertype == 1) {
      radioButton1.setSelcted(true);

  } else {
      radioButton2.setSelcted(true);
  }
```